# Show that the Green's operator $G(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty(T_t\alpha-H\alpha)dt$ is well definied.

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, heat-equation

Let $T_t\alpha$ be the unique solution of the cauchy problem
$$\frac{\partial A(x,t)}{\partial t}=-\Delta A(x,t)$$
$$A(x,0)=\alpha$$
We know that $T_t\alpha$ converges in $L^2$ to an $L^2$ form $H\alpha$, that $||T_t||^2$ is (nonstrictly) decreasing and that $T_0\alpha=\alpha$.

I wanna show that  $G(\alpha):=\int_0^\infty(T_t\alpha-H\alpha)dt$ is well defined. For that I'm trying to show that I'm trying to show that $||T_t\alpha(x)-H\alpha(x)||$ decays fastly enough. I see that this decays to zero, but how does it guarantee that that integral converges? Using that $H$ is harmonic, I've also shown that this norm is (nonstrictly) decreasing.

Comment: "$T_t\alpha$ converges in $L^2$ to an $L^2$ form $H\alpha$" as what? $t\to 0$, $t\to+\infty$, ...?

Comment: I think he means $ \  \  \displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty} \lVert T_t (\alpha) - H(\alpha) \rVert_{L^2} = 0$

Comment: Are you working on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or on a more general Riemannian manifold? In the first case we have $H\alpha=0$ (if you mean it as the $L^2$ limit of $T_t\alpha$ as $t\to+\infty$) and $G(\alpha)$ can be defined by a Laplace transform as you did if $n\geq 3$ thanks to the time decay of order $O(t^{-\frac{n}{2}})$ for the heat kernel.

Comment: I'm working with Riemannian manifolds. And it is when $t\to\infty$

Comment: I'm following the "Algebraic Geometry over the Complex Numbers", by Donu Arapura.